# Oracle java stored procedure creating zip file - java.security.AccessControlException: the Permission

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I made java oracle stored procedure that creates zip files. And the zip file name is changed every time when running the procedure.

But every time it requires new grant permission like below,

```
dbms_java.grant_permission('GILBERT','SYS:java.io.FilePermission','C:\Test\20170817.zip','write')
```

I can not give the permission every time when creating zip file.
Any solution for this?

```
- OS: Windows7
- Oracle: 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: You should just give access rights to the c:\test folder.

Comment: Yes, I did it already. But it requires again for the zip file. dbms_java.grant_permission( 'GILBERT', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'C:\Test', 'read, write, delete, execute');